# Problem with creating AWS Lambda function using Micronaut and GraalVM

Tags: java, docker, aws-lambda, micronaut, graalvm

I'm trying to create and deploy AWS Lambda function in Java using Micronaut, GraalVM, and Docker. I'm following [this tutorial](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/guide/#customRuntimes) to create AWS lambda with GraalVM runtime.

I've created java project using `micronaut` command `$ mn create-app my-app --features aws-api-gateway-graal`. And then without any change in code or config files, try to build a Docker image with GraalVM native image. In the step of docker build when graalvm native image is building I get these warnings:

> Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build. No instances are allowed in
>   the image heap for a class that is initialized or reinitialized at
>   image runtime com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.ContainerConfig.
>   Try marking this class for build-time initialization with
>   --initialize-at-build-time=com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.ContainerConfig
>
> ```
> Detailed message:
> Trace:     field io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.AbstractLambdaContainerHandler.config
> ```
>
> Warning: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying
>   exception*
>
> Warning: Image 'server' is a fallback image that requires a JDK for
>   execution (use --no-fallback to suppress fallback image generation).

After build I export docker image with bootstrap file to function.zip file as it's written in tutorial. Then I upload function.zip file to my created AWS lambda function and when I try to test function I get this error:

> ```
> {  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
>    "errorMessage": "RequestId: 888854d7-0e0e-42b4-a138-9a003c3455e1 Error: Runtime exited with error:
>     exit status 1"
> }
> ```
>
> START RequestId: 888854d7-0e0e-42b4-a138-9a003c3455e1 Version:
>   $LATEST
>   **Error: No bin/java and no environment variable JAVA_HOME**
>  END RequestId: 888854d7-0e0e-42b4-a138-9a003c3455e1
>  REPORT RequestId:
>   888854d7-0e0e-42b4-a138-9a003c3455e1  Duration: 415.09 ms Billed
>   Duration: 500 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB  
>   RequestId: 888854d7-0e0e-42b4-a138-9a003c3455e1 Error: Runtime exited
>   with error: exit status 1
>  Runtime.ExitError

I don't know what is wrong. I haven't found any solution for this problem yet.

Comment: Try checking JAVA_HOME is set in the environment

Comment: What environment you mean? In my Linux machine java is installed and JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This classes invokes static method `defaultConfig` of the `ContainerConfig` class.

```
io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.AbstractLambdaContainerHandler
com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler
```

To resolve the issue we need to to initialize that classes at run-time instead of compile time.

I'm totally new to GraalVM and for now can't explain what the reason of that.

My `native-image` configurations.

```
native-image 
--delay-class-initialization-to-runtime=io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.AbstractLambdaContainerHandler,com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler
--no-fallback
--no-server 
-cp build/libs/yourJarName.jar
```

Resources:
https://medium.com/graalvm/understanding-class-initialization-in-graalvm-native-image-generation-d765b7e4d6ed