# How to run Spring Boot in GraalVM without JRE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, class, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to run Spring Boot application using GraalVM Native. After successful compilation into single file, I can easily run binary, Spring Boot starts normally, but when I trying to run it inside docker with `ubuntu` image (it not contains java, but simple HelloWorld in GraalVM native works without JRE) I getting this error:

```
Error: No bin/java and no environment variable JAVA_HOME
```

I've read that I probably need to init classes at runtime instead of compile time (from: [Problem with creating AWS Lambda function using Micronaut and GraalVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735749/problem-with-creating-aws-lambda-function-using-micronaut-and-graalvm)). But I don't know which classes should I pass to `--delay-class-initialization-to-runtime`. How can I run my Spring Boot app without JRE?

Comment: How/where did you compile your Spring app into Graal Native Image? The Docker container's base image (`FROM baseimageName` - in your case `ubuntu`) needs to *match exactly* the base image or machine your app was compiled on, since the process creates an 100% machine specific (native) compiled executable. The easiest way to run your app inside a Docker container, is to build it inside the same container (or at least the same base image) - see this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-graalvm/blob/master/Dockerfile) as an example.

Comment: You need to pass graalvm `--no-fallback` arg to build a entirely standalone executable